# Log4mongo for Java: Could not instantiate appender named MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, log4j, mongodb-java

Log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, MongoDB
log4j.appender.MongoDB=org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender
log4j.appender.MongoDB.databaseName=appName
log4j.appender.MongoDB.collectionName=test
```

When I build the application I get an error,
Could not instantiate appender named "MongoDB"

The same log4j.properties work for the sample example in link[http://log4mongo.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1474614]

Comment: Are you certain you have the [log4mongo jar file](http://log4mongo.org/display/PUB/Downloads) in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, the jar log4mongo-java-0.7.0.jar is added in the classpath. Our project uses maven. Do we have to add the maven dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: I had to add the mongodb jars in the lib folder and it worked.